# TypeError: _babelCore.OptionManager is not a function

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, babeljs

I installing all node modules for React native. When i going to build iOS project i got error on terminal

```
~/WebWork/Project/Project/node_modules/react-native/packager ~
/Users/User/WebWork/Project/Project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:112
  var opts = new /*istanbul ignore next*/_babelCore.OptionManager().init( /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _extend2.default)( /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _cloneDeep2.default)(transformOpts), {
             ^

TypeError: _babelCore.OptionManager is not a function
    at compile (/Users/User/WebWork/Project/MyProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:112:14)
    at loader (/Users/User/WebWork/Project/MyProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/User/WebWork/Project/MyProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Gaurav/WebWork/Project/TelMed/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:16:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
~
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

And on iOS device i got "Could not connect to development server"

For this issue i was trying to do following process but nothing much get help from it

```
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
```

I'm interested to know why this error occurs.

Comment: First, the reason you're not able to connect to the dev server is because of that error. What version of node (`node -v`), npm (`npm -v`), and react native are you using?

Comment: @BradBumbalough v5.9.1

Comment: What about npm and react-native?

Comment: @BradBumbalough npm 3.7.3 and react native 0.22.2

Comment: Have you tried deleting your node_modules folder and rerunning `npm install`?

Comment: @BradBumbalough sorry i forgot to wrote up step that's i have tried please look at question again i edited and steps of cleaning all .

Comment: @BradBumbalough do you any hint on it?